# In a tree, can a child have multiple parents?

Tags: database, data-structures, tree, relationship, parent-child

I am developing an application that contains multiple features and each feature has multiple functions. I represented this as a tree but some functions use other functions which means a child can have more than one parent (if I am not wrong). How it is possible in a tree data structure? Can I access the child node from another parent's child node? If so how can I implement this? Can graphs help me with this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If a node has more than two parents, your data structure is no longer a tree. E.g., to quote [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology):

> A node has at most one parent, but possibly many ancestor nodes, such as the parent's parent.

If you need a data structure where a child can have multiple parents, you should look into a (directed) graph.

Comment: Can I access a node from another node(not the parent or parent's parent node)?

Answer (score 0):

a [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=tree%20enables%20two%20parents%20of%20one%20childe&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIL883IL883&oq=tree%20enables%20two%20parents%20of%20one%20childe&aqs=chrome..69i57.23825j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gives the answer that:

"Yes, you can have nodes have both “children” and “parents”. However that is no longer a tree structured graph, so you will not be able to use a TreeModel"

[Original reference](https://forum.nwoods.com/t/is-it-possible-for-a-node-to-have-multiple-parents/6349)

Comment: Can I access a node from another node(not the parent or parent's parent node)?